# Is it possible to make a capacitor of required specifications using aluminium foil?

Tags: experimental-physics, capacitance, home-experiment, electronics

I wanted to make a FM radio transmitter but I was not able to get a capacitor with the exact rating of certain micro farad and pF. But I live in a poor country and I can not find them in the local store and don't have a store like RadioShack, even though I got my hands on a transistor.

I saw a certain video on the internet, which showed a way to make capacitors using the aluminium foil and paper. By placing the aluminium foils on top of each other and keeping paper as a dielectric.

But my question is will I be able to make the capacitor of required specifications using the formula$$C=\frac{\epsilon_0A}{d}$$

The reason why I am asking this question is that I don't have a meter that can measure the capacitance. I can't afford it for a certain reason. So will there be any problem or is there some details still required. If so then please help with required maths and give a hint to continue my work. Sorry if my question is silly, I am helpless.

Comment: Please take a look at the [FAQ on writing question titles](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles).

Comment: It is possible, but you still need means of verifying your result, so it doesn't solve your problem. Having said that, you can buy precise capacitors for this task for less than what a roll of aluminum foil will cost you, so it's a total waste of your time to even try. I would also say that building an FM transmitter is probably not a good project for a variety of reasons, some of which are legal and have to do with personal responsibility. You could, whether you want it, or not, endanger people by blocking emergency frequencies. Don't do that.

Comment: @CuriousOne I have checked my local law. But the problem regarding the capacitor is not cost but are not available. I am still trying to get one cheap multi meter.

Comment: Even if you had checked your law it still doesn't remove any kind of personal responsibility for your actions. Those exist even without the law. Since you have access to the internet, you are very likely to live in a country (India?) that has a very well working electronics distributor network. Check for one of the usual suspects. How about Mouser?

Comment: Note that capacitors have multiple parameters: there is the capacitance (what you want - in pF or nF or µF), the voltage rating (strength of dielectric), but then there are "parasitics" that become increasingly important with frequency: inductance, loss tangent, and leakage. For your device to work reliably all of these need to be within reasonable specs - which can be hard to do with home construction. I agree with @CuriousOne - you really should make an effort to obtain the component you need; and be very careful about accidentally creating a jammer.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't buy one online? I mean, sure I can accept not having such a "brick & mortar" location to purchase them near you, but if you've got the internet, what's preventing you from buying it the "modern" way?

Comment: This formula assumes that the capacitor is infinitely big (the electric field is homogeneous, so the effects of the edges of the capacitor are neglected). Also note that paper is a dielectric which also has an effect of the capacity.